# How do I change text on button labels within a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, localization

I have a frame, let's say:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label1 = G.tk.Label(self, text="Change me!")
        label1.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        label2 = G.tk.Label(self, text="Change me too!")
        label2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
```

Now I would like to be able to change the "Change me!" and "Change me too!" texts both by pressing a button on the page. In my implementation this is for localisation purposes.

My current implementation just has separate frames for each language but that is incredibly cumbersome to maintain. I would like to just have one frame for each page of content, and only change the text that is displayed. Is that possible?

I've seen `StringVar` thrown around in documentation but not with a very clear guide on how to use it.

Comment: use `self.` to have access to labels in other methods.

Comment: you don't have to use `StringVar` to change text - you can do it directly `label1["text"] ="new text"` But you have to use `self.label1` to have access to label in other methods.

Comment: It depends on how you structure your labels. 1st option: you can store all of your labels in a `list`, which you would declare on `__init__`, and iterate thru. 2nd option: you can iterate thru inherited `children` dict, where you would check type of each children for `label` and so on (there an option to do this recursively for nested frames). In both cases changing the text of a label will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `self.label1` and `self.label2` to have access to labels in other methods.

You can assing function to `Button` and use `self.label["text"] = "new text"`

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Change me!")
        self.label1.pack()

        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Change me too!")
        self.label2.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Change", command=self.change_text)
        button.pack()

    def change_text(self):
        self.label1["text"] = "New text!"
        self.label2["text"] = "New text too!"

root = tk.Tk()

Page1(root, None).pack()

root.mainloop()
```